# Serializing an object with a string property containing double quotes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a object which has a string property that has a value with double quotes in it. I need to serialize this object and then use that XML. I **wont be deserializing** this xml.

I am having trouble getting the right content in the XML file. Let me explain with a code sample:

```
[Serializable]
public class Test {
    [XmlElement]
    public string obj { get; set; }
}
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var st ="Priority == \"1\"";
        Test test = new Test();          
        test.obj = st;
        //Serialize this object
        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
        StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, new XmlWriterSettings {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true
        });
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();//just to make things simpler here
        ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, test, ns);
        //My XML
        var xml = sww.ToString();
    }
}
```

I need my xml to be:

```
<Test><obj>Priority==&quot;1&quot;</obj></Test>
```

I now get:

```
<Test><obj>Priority==\"1\"</obj></Test>
```

I even tried to encode the string into HTML using `var html = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(st);`
In this case, the varible `html` is in the right format however on serializing I get:

```
<Test><obj>Priority==&amp;quot;1&amp;quot;</obj></Test>
```

Need some help please.

Comment: No, you did not get `\"1\"`. You were looking at the string in the debugger, weren't you? And what happened to the second "=" sign?

Comment: @johnSaunders Yeah, thats the mistake I made. I was reading the comment on the debugger which isn't what comes out when written. And i spent so much time on THIS :(

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you actually get. In fact, you could add your actual results as an answer, since I'm sure others will make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with the code.

I actually get`<Test><obj>Priority=="1"</obj></Test>` and this is fine. The mistake I was making was that I was reading the value on the debugger. When I write it somewhere, the content was in the correct format.

The `"` didnt get converted to `&quot;` because double quotes are as such accepted in an XML document. I can work with that in this case!